# Why compiler thinks that result of expression 1 + m=6 + 2 is boolean?

Tags: java

Why compiler thinks that the expression `1 + m=6 + 2` is evaluated to boolean? **Compiler (Eclipse) says that the result of this expression is *boolean*. Why?** Priority of = is lowest, so first + is done and `1+m` shall fail with "unitialized local variable" compile error. If I declare `int m = 1;` then expression above shall fail as (1+1) = (6+2) => 2=8 is not allowed.

```
class Driver {

    static void f(int arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m;

        f( 1 + m=6 + 2); // c.ERR 

        f( 1 + (m=6) + 2); // prints 9  
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact and complete error from the compiler? javac says; "Error:(13, 14) java: unexpected type
  required: variable
  found:    value*.

Comment: If that's what eclipse says, eclipse is wrong. It's just an invalid expression, it can't have a specific type.

Comment: - Syntax error on token "=", <= expected
 - The method f(int) in the type Driver is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: So it apparently doesn't really believe it's a boolean expression. It says there is a syntax error, it makes a bet regarding what your intention is (i.e. compare two values, which would require a comparison operator rather than an assignment operator), and, based on this bet, it tells you that your intention doesn't make sense because it would pass a boolean expression to a method expecting an int. The crux is, the first error is "syntax error". The rest is Eclipse trying to help and show as many errors at once as possible.

Comment: It's an invalid expression. Eclipse is trying to do a little assumption here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quoting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) :

> The evaluation of an arithmetical expression is controlled by three
>   sets of rules: precedence rules, associativity rules, and order rules.
>
> **Precedence** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should
>   be parenthesized when the expression mixes different kinds of
>   operators.
>
> **Associativity** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression
>   should be parenthesized when the expression has a bunch of the same
>   kind of operator.
>
> **Order** of evaluation rules describe the order in which each operand in
>   an expression is evaluated.

```
//Evluation order
f( 1 + m=6 + 2); 
 - 1+ m =>ERR
  - 6+2 = 8 => ok
   - 1+m = 8 => ERR

f( 1 + (m=6) + 2);
 - m=6 => ok
  - 1+6 = 7 => ok
   - 7+2 = 9 => ok
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific error doesn't make sense, but without those parentheses, you're trying to assign the right-hand side to the result of `1 + m`, which obviously you can't do. The parentheses change the order of operations so the `m=6` happens first, and then the two additions.